# Java skydrive rest file uploading

Tags: java, rest, onedrive

I tried uploading a file to skydrive with the rest api in java.

Here is my code:

```
    public void UploadFile(File upfile) {
    if (upload_loc == null) {
        getUploadLocation();
    }

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(upload_loc + "?" + "access_token=" + access_token);
    try {

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(null,"A300x",null);
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(upfile, "multipart/form-data");
        mpEntity.addPart("file", cbFile);

        post.setEntity(mpEntity);
        System.out.println(post.toString());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line2 = "";
        while ((line2 = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line2);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Onlab.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

}
```

But when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
{
"error": {
  "code": "request_body_invalid", 
  "message": "The request entity body for multipart form-data POST isn't valid. The expected format is:\u000d\u000a--[boundary]\u000d\u000aContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"[FileName]\"\u000d\u000aContent-Type: application/octet-stream\u000d\u000a[CR][LF]\u000d\u000a[file contents]\u000d\u000a--[boundary]--[CR][LF]"
 }
}
```

My biggest problem is that I don't see the request itself. I couldn't find any usable toString method for that. I tried this forced boundary format, but I tried it with empty constructor too.

My file is now a txt with some text, and I think the boundary is the main problem or I should be configuring some more parameters. When I see the variables in debugging mode everything looks the same as a guide in the msdn.

I'm new in the rest world and if it possible I want to keep this apache lib with the simple to use HttpClient and HttpPost classes.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my english.

EDIT:
Ok, after a long sleep I decided to try the PUT method instead of POST. The code work fine with minimal changes:

```
public void UploadFile(File upfile) {
    if (upload_loc == null) {
        getUploadLocation();
    }
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    String fname=upfile.getName();
    HttpPut put= new HttpPut(upload_loc +"/"+fname+ "?" + "access_token=" + access_token);
    try {
        FileEntity reqEntity=new FileEntity(upfile);
        put.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line2 = "";
        while ((line2 = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line2);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Onlab.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

But there is no answer for the first question yet.

Comment: You could use wireshark to trace the HTTP request?

Comment: Not really, I'm sitting in a 1000 computers network, and I get 200 pocket /sec if I try to use filters it still noisy. I tryed this but painful :)

Comment: If you know the remote host, that should be a good enough filter?  Maybe try [HttpClient's logging](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html) instead?

Comment: And i still can't decode the https pockets :)

Comment: http://varuntayur.wordpress.com/2013/06/11/howto-skydrive-rest-api-crud-example/

Answer (score 3):

Two quick things:

1. You should not be using the overloaded `MultipartEntity` constructor unless you really need to. In this case you are setting the charset to null, which is probably not a good idea. Also, your boundary delimiter is not complex enough.
2. Your file body content type should reflect the content of the actual file being uploaded. `multipart-formdata is normally used for HTML form data, not files. You should change this to 'text/plain', or 'image/jpeg', or whatever reflects the true mime type of the file.

Some great tools for debugging REST requests - [REST Console (Chrome)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en), [REST Client (Firefox)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/).

Some quick notes on the error message you received, it actually has quite a bit of detail. The service is expecting the following parameters to be set for the file part being sent:

- name:
- filename:
- Content-Type: application/octet-stream

You can have the HTTP client set most of these with this code:

```
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(
    upfile,
    "yourFileNameHere",
    "application/octet-stream",
    "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I tryed the empty Multipart constructor and that not worked like now this. I tryed some more body type not helped too. I think it will be a very little problem what I dont see.

Comment: @tg44 - did you also change the content type? See edit to my answer which may be helpful as well.

Comment: Still not working, by the way I think the mpEntry.addFile do this for me. If I check the variables in debug mode i see the filename parameter in the post variable.